# User suddenly changed to nobody, and is restored when changing permission to a file

Tags: linux, permissions, users, git

I was learning about git internals, doing basic commands, when suddenly I encountered this error: **fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at..**. I then noticed that the user is **nobody**. I have no idea how did the user suddenly change to nobody, and what confuses me even more is when I changed the permessions of a file to 777 (after deleting the .git repo, and git init-ing again) the user was restored, and git didn't show any error as before.

Comment: hard to debug without knowing what you did. Did you perhaps copy over a git repo as-is from a different machine? Ran `git` with `sudo`, or something?

Comment: Is the repository that of a web page? The user `nobody` is usually used by daemons to drop privileges.

Comment: User nobody can also appear with NFS (eg: root_squash) or with Linux user namespaces (containers...) for the overflow user. OP has to give more information.